# Why am i getting this error and how to solve it

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, input

After every part of my code i print something to see what its working what is not. For instance my program has multiple inputs. For example 3 its from how many numbers there are to read, and 2 its how many iteration i will do to every number later:

```
3 2
231 31 56
```

I was just trying to take every number and splitting them into numerals. (231 in 2 3 1)

```py
n_k=raw_input().split()
n=int(n_k[0])
k=int(n_k[1])

numbers=[]
for i in range(n):
    numbers.append(raw_input())

for number in numbers:
    number=str(number)
    numerals=[int(x) for x in number]

print (numerals)
```

I get this error:

```
   numbers.append(raw_input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: It's in the docs of raw_input() https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

Comment: I've read them before i posted this. I can't understand what is wrong with my code.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the inputs you gave. Your code is NOT particularly wrong, it's your inputs. You get EOF which stands for End Of File, you input an EOF. You can handle it with a try-except statement.

Comment: `k` variable is unused

Comment: Your code as written is expecting one number per line (after the header with two numbers), not all of them on one line as your example input shows.

Answer (score 1):

You get `EOFError` probably because you terminate the program while it waits for your input.

---

If I got it right, you need to ask user for some numbers and then print digits for each.

It can be done a little bit easier:

```py
# python2.7
numbers = map(int, raw_input("Enter some numbers: ").split())
for number in numbers:
    print [int(x) for x in str(number)]
```

Input and output:

> Enter some numbers: `12 0 182 3214`
>   [1, 2]
>   [0]
>   [1, 8, 2]
>   [3, 2, 1, 4]